# Using Content Security Policy in AMP-HTML pages?

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a site built with [AMP](https://amp.dev).

I tried to use `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'`, but all styles and designs didn't show properly since they are loaded from `cdn.ampproject.org`.

Google, in their AMP documentation, says that all Content Security Policy has been handled before stored in their repository.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found this on [scotthelme.co.uk](https://scotthelme.co.uk). Here's the script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Security-Policy: script-src https://cdn.ampproject.org:*');
?>
```

And, it works as I wish when I check it on [securityheaders.io](https://securityheaders.io).

Comment: That looks like the right solution. If you want to be able to load scripts from your own domain as well, you should add `'self'` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Restrictive CSP for AMP it's not easy, because now (Q2 2020) not all CSP headers are supported in all browsers. For example `style-src-elem` is supported in Chrome, but not in FF. Maybe sometimes at the future it will be easier.

For now it's like this:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'none';base-uri 'self';manifest-src 'self';script-src 'self' https://cdn.ampproject.org;script-src-elem https://cdn.ampproject.org;style-src 'unsafe-inline';connect-src https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://cdn.ampproject.org/;img-src 'self';form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'none';sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts;upgrade-insecure-requests;block-all-mixed-content;
```

`default-src` will set default restrictively to '`none`' but this default it's **not** setting all possible properties, that's why it's there for example `frame-ancestors 'none';`, this property is not set by `default-src`.

`style-src 'unsafe-inline'` because with AMP only inline styles are possible.

`connect-src https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://cdn.ampproject.org/` possible to load AMP parts and send analytics data with `amp-analytics`

`script-src 'self' https://cdn.ampproject.org` to run local javascripts (a few ones which are possible to run on AMP) and AMP CND

`script-src-elem https://cdn.ampproject.org` is applied on scripts at external files only. So I don't need `'self'` because AMP don't allows me to use them.

Other properties set to `'self'` allows me to use same-domain hosted resources only (images, manifest, service worker, …)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help friends in the Google AMP community. Try my concoction (this is for NGINX servers, you can customize it for use with httpd servers):

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "base-uri 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; script-src * 'self' blob: https://apis.google.com https://apis.google.com https://cdn.ampproject.org; script-src-elem * 'unsafe-inline' data: blob: https: // cdn. ampproject.org; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; connect-src * https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https: //googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://adservice.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://cdn.ampproject.org/; img-src * data: https: / /cdn.ampproject.org; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts; upgrade-insecure-requests; block-all-mixed -content; font-src * 'self' data: https://cloud.typography.com https://fast.fonts.net https://fonts.googleapis.com https://use.typekit.net https: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn .com https://use.fontawesome.com; " always;
```

Comment: are the spaces intentional or added by stackexchange?  I pasted this in and my webserver wouldn't start.